# What is the best technology for concurrent web page sessions?

Tags: node.js, session, express

What is the recommended technology or technologies to use in order to make a web page that automatically updates the screen depending on a value change in a database?

For example, there is a web page with a button. When the button is pressed, a corresponding value in a database is changed from off to on. When this is completed, the database is checked again and the button on the web page changes to the corresponding state (either on or off).

Several web pages may be open on different devices and they must also change.

I have looked into Node.js with Express and Socket.io but it seems to have relatively little documentation and I was wondering if this can all just be accomplished in another way since JavaScript is pretty slow (I think).

Comment: look up [Server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) and particularily http server push.

Comment: I can't give you an answer, because I don't know all the different technologies that well, but; Node.js should be find for this. JS might be slow, but thankfully googles v8 engine works is magic ways, so the js is actually compiled to c or something and run natively. So it is pretty fast. This is why the chrome browser is so awesome (other browsers might do this as well). There is quite a bit of documentation on nodejs in my experience, so I don't see what the big issue is there.

Answer (score 1):

[Meteor JS](http://meteor.com) might interest you, if you don't mind its bleeding edge status. Its very fancy javascript framework that does a lot of realtime updates and concurrency. Very cool.

Comment: +1 to Meteor. There's also Derby and SocketStream.

Comment: Yarek, is Meteor JS still regarded as alpha? If not, would you update this answer?

Comment: @halfer No idea, I don't work with frontend anymore :)